# Что это за связь между классами uml, как расшифровать?

Tags: java, uml

На диаграмме два класса связаны с друг другом связь агрегат. Поясните пожалуйста:

1. Почему агрегатом связывают два класса?
2. Что означает стрелка на линии связи, направленная на класс "Видимость"?
3. Что означает цифры 0..3 рядом с классом "видимость"? Это типа "Видимость" можно создать в количестве о или 3?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала определимся:

1. Целая часть - это **Наблюдения за погодой**
2. Составная часть -  это **Видимость**

### Разница между агрегацией и композицией

У вас на схеме показана не агрегация, а **композиция**. Композиция обозначается закрашенным ромбиком, как бы показывая что такая составная часть не может выйти за пределы целой части. Для начала хочется заметить, что такая связь предьявляет в отличии от агрегации более серьезные требования к жизненному циклу составных частей. Тоесть, уничтожение внутренних обьектов должно происходить вместе с уничтожением основного обьекта, следовательно составная часть должна создаваться внутри целой части.

Агрегация же не управляет жизненным циклом составной части и подразумевает, что составной обьект может быть создан вне целой части. Время их жизни не связано. Это очень тонкая грань, которую требуется понять. Агрегация обозначается ромбиком без закрашивания.

### Читаем вашу диаграмму

Целая часть "Наблюдения за погодой" имеет (has a) внутри себя составную часть "Видимость" (стрелочка с ромбиком), общее количество которых может быть в интервале от 0 до 3 (цифры над составной частью).

На основе этого вы можете написать программный код.

**Пример программного кода:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WeatherObservations observation = new WeatherObservations(10.5, 760.5);

        try {
            observation.addVisibility(10, 0, true);
            observation.addVisibility(10, 0, true);
            observation.addVisibility(10, 0, true);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Limit reached...");
        }
    }
}

class Visibility {
    private Integer min;
    private Integer max;
    private Boolean visabilityIsAbsent;

    public Visibility(Integer min, Integer max, Boolean visabilityIsAbsent) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.visabilityIsAbsent = visabilityIsAbsent;
    }

    public Integer getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public Boolean getVisabilityIsAbsent() {
        return visabilityIsAbsent;
    }
}


class WeatherObservations {

    private double temperature;
    private double pressure;
    private ArrayList < Visibility > visibilities;

    public WeatherObservations(double temperature, double pressure) {
        this.visibilities = new ArrayList < Visibility > ();
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public void addVisibility(Integer min, Integer max, Boolean visabilityIsAbsent) throws Throwable {
        if (visibilities.size() < 3) {
            Visibility visibility = new Visibility(min, max, visabilityIsAbsent);
            visibilities.add(visibility);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Limit reached");
        }
    }
}
```

### Полезные ссылки:

1. [Видео про разницу между агрегацией и композицией на UML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8GRjeHzgpQ)
2. [Наследование vs Композиция vs Агрегация](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/12/vs-vs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Агрегация - это один из видов связей между классами на UML-диаграммах классов. Агрегация представляется стрелкой с незакрашенным ромбиком на конце. У вас на схеме ромбик закрашен, поэтому эта связь - композиция.
Агрегация и композиция похожи и обе подразумевают отношение "часть - целое" между классами (как колесо есть часть машины), но всё же у них имеются различия. Агрегация позволяет классу-части существовать до создания класса целого, и после его уничтожения. Композиция же подразумевает, что класс-часть создаётся и уничтожается вместе с классом-целым.
В вашей схеме класс "Видимость" является частью класса "Наблюдения за погодой", причём на один объект "Наблюдения за погодой" может быть создано от 0 до 3 объектов "Видимость".
Между классами на UML-диаграммах бывают различные отношения: ассоциация, агрегация, композиция, наследование, реализация, зависимость.

Информация взята [отсюда](https://beauty-of-java.site/oop/uml-diagrammy-klassov/). Там есть подробное описание отношений между классами и картинки по этой теме.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, это композиция. Как говорится на [Хабре](https://habr.com/post/325478/)

```
композиция — это когда один объект предоставляет другому свою функциональность частично или полностью.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий и ссылку!